# Remap key in Autohotkey but wrong tone mark

Tags: autohotkey

I use[Unikey](https://www.unikey.org/) program to write Vietnamese, when i try to use autohotkey program to remap key, when writing letters, the tone mark is not displayed correctly, can anyone help.Ex:

```
1::Send, p
2::Send, o
3::Send, i
4::Send, u
5::Send, y
```

RESULT:  caí, gaí, thaỏ...(wrong)-->cái, gái, thảo...(right)

I use code in [this link](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/1257-half-qwerty-one-handed-typing/), it's very well written, but I have to type the space key too much, so I was going to remap some keys to make it easier to type but got this error.

Comment: Try the [Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Text) e.g. `Send {Text}thảo`

Answer (score 0):

```
mirror_1 = 6
mirror_2 = 7
mirror_3 = 8
mirror_4 = 9
mirror_5 = 0
mirror_q = 1
mirror_w = 2
mirror_e = 3
mirror_r = 4
mirror_t = 5
mirror_a = `;
mirror_s = l
mirror_d = k
mirror_f = j
mirror_g = h
mirror_z = /
mirror_x = .
mirror_c = ,
mirror_v = m
mirror_b = n
mirror_6 = 5
mirror_7 = 4
mirror_8 = 3
mirror_9 = 2
mirror_0 = 1
mirror_y = 5
mirror_u = 4
mirror_i = 3
mirror_o = 2
mirror_p = 1
mirror_h = g
mirror_j = f
mirror_k = d
mirror_l = s
mirror_n = b
mirror_m = v
return


; This key may help, as the space-on-up may get annoying, especially if you type fast.
Control & Space::Suspend

; These keys are optional, but they may help if you are typing on the left-hand side.
CapsLock::Send, {BackSpace}
Space & CapsLock::Send, {Enter}

; If spacebar didn't modify anything, send a real space keystroke upon release.
space::
Send {space}
return

space & 1::
space & 2::
space & 3::
space & 4::
space & 5::
space & q::
space & w::
space & e::
space & r::
space & t::
space & a::
space & s::
space & d::
space & f::
space & g::
space & z::
space & x::
space & c::
space & v::
space & b::
space & `;::
space & ,::
space & .::
space & /::
space & 6::
space & 7::
space & 8::
space & 9::
space & 0::
space & y::
space & u::
space & i::
space & o::
space & p::
space & h::
space & j::
space & k::
space & l::
space & n::
space & m::
; Determine the mirror key, if there is one:
if A_ThisHotkey = space & `;
   MirrorKey = a
else if A_ThisHotkey = space & ,
   MirrorKey = c
else if A_ThisHotkey = space & .
   MirrorKey = x
else if A_ThisHotkey = space & /
   MirrorKey = z
else  ; To avoid runtime errors due to invalid var names, do this part last.
{
   StringRight, ThisKey, A_ThisHotkey, 1
   StringTrimRight, MirrorKey, mirror_%ThisKey%, 0  ; Retrieve "array" element.
   if MirrorKey =  ; No mirror, script probably needs adjustment.
      return
}

Modifiers =
GetKeyState, state1, LWin
GetKeyState, state2, RWin
state = %state1%%state2%
if state <> UU  ; At least one Windows key is down.
   Modifiers = %Modifiers%#
GetKeyState, state1, Control
if state1 = D
   Modifiers = %Modifiers%^
GetKeyState, state1, Alt
if state1 = D
   Modifiers = %Modifiers%!
GetKeyState, state1, Shift
if state1 = D
   Modifiers = %Modifiers%+
Send %Modifiers%{%MirrorKey%}
return


1::p
2::o
3::i
4::u
5::y
return
```